# sed using dollar sign for both environment variable and end-of-line pattern matching

Tags: bash, sed, environment-variables

In `sed`, we use double quotes to read environment variable indicated by a dollar sign, what should i do if I want to use the dollar sign for end-of-line pattern at the same time?

Here is example of my command (not working),

```
cat inputfile | xargs -n4 sh -c 'sed -ne "$1,$2p" bigfile|sed -e "$s/$/\n+--$3-----+/" > $0.outputfile'
```

I pipe the content of a input file (containing the output filename, target line number (start and end), and some tags to add to each file) to `xargs` which break the big file into smaller files. Example of input file:

```
dataA
59
88
sometagA
dataB
91
236
sometagB
....
```

In the second `sed` command: `sed -e "$s/$/\n+--$3-----+/"`, `$3` is environment variable from `xargs`, and i want to use the other $s and $ to target end-of-file and end-of-line pattern respectively, as i intent to insert some tags to each output file. I cannot use single and double quote at the same time as the outter `xargs` already used single quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backslash to escape a dollar sign from the shell.

```
xargs -n4 sh -c 'sed -ne "$1,$2p" bigfile |
    sed -e "\$s/\$/\n+--$3-----+/" > "$0".outputfile' <inputfile
```

You only pass four arguments and they are numbered from zero, so I guess you mean `$3`, not `$4`.

Notice also how to avoid the [useless `cat`.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

The two `sed` scripts could probably be merged into something like

```
sed -n "$1,$2!d;$2{;s/\$/+--$3-----+/p;q;}p"
```

Answer (score 1):

escape it from `bash shell` to have an end anchor

```
sed -ne "$1,$2p" bigfile|sed -e "$s/\$/\n+--$3-----+/"
```

escape it once more from `sed` to have a literal dollar sign e.g;

```
sed -ne "$1,$2p" bigfile|sed -e "$s/\$/\n+--$3-----+/| sed 's/.*/& pays \\$99/'
```